# Movement multi person pose estimation does not import

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, pose

I previously used Movenet for multi person pose estimation. However, just today it got an error when importing the multipose lightning model as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

model = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/movenet/multipose/lightning/1")
movenet = model.signatures['serving_default']
```

Then I got the following error:

```
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: /var/folders/tc/c08qbx_s61bbx4bxq4rt8wxw0000gn/T/tfhub_modules/312f001449331ee3d410d758fccdc9945a65dbc3/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

I don't understand why it does not work, as it has worked before and on the site of Tensorflow it is explained to be done just like this. Does anyone know what could be going wrong? I also did download the model to my own device via the import link, but I cannot find how to import it from my local files to my program. Does anyone know how this is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not getting errors executing your code. Have you updated / installed any package lately? Try updating tensorflow and tensorflow_hub if you can.

Comment: Yes I have updated all packages, but it returns the same error unfortunately. Do you maybe know how to import the manually downloaded model from the link (https://tfhub.dev/google/movenet/multipose/lightning/1) into my python program, thus from my local files. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Is the downloaded model in format model.pb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to load the model through `tensorflow_hub` looks ok. However you can try loading the model manually, first downloading the `.pb` file into a folder and then loading it with keras function [`load_model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/load_model), like this:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('path/to/folder')
```

Comment: This worked using the line; model = tf.saved_model.load('path/to/folder'). Thanks a lot!